# Django REST framework APIView vs Viewset

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am currently using an `APIView` for a url (`'/api/events/<int:pk>'`), but I can't use this same APIView for the `list` view as there is no distinction between **list** (get all) and **detail** (get 1). This view is unrelated to a model, because I am calling an externel API.

The `ViewSet` does have distinction between list and retrieve, but if I use that, I HAVE to use the serializer_classes. But, I don't have a serializer on this view.

I know I can create a second APIView so I have 1 for both the detail and the list view, but I find that a little cumbersome. It's cleaner to have it in 1 class.

What to do best?

Example:"

```
class TestView(APIView):
    """
    Test123123o8
    """
    serializer_class = Test1Serializer

    #this methods acts on the /test GET route
    def get(self, request):
        return Response(Test.objects.all())

    # route that acts on the DETAIL route (for example '/api/test/1'). 
    # How to implement this in the URL?
    def get_detail(self, request, pk):
        return Response(test.objects.get(pk=pk))
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = Test1Serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Please add your api view, what is that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Gabriel ok I added example. I have a get and a get_detail method. in my urls.py I will have to entries, 1 with /test and 1 with /test/1 and I want to use this APIView for both of them

Comment: From your example looks like you have a queryset `Test.objects.all()` and it's serializer so why not using a `viewset` ?? If needed in a `viewset` you can have different serializer class for list/detail, just subclass `get_serializer_class` method and check `self.action`

Comment: Sorry you are right but I dont have a queryset, I am implemennting a layer around another API

Comment: Then you should stick with the normal `APIView`, have one view class that checks in `get` method kwargs sent for the request. And then have 2 different urls one for the list and other for detail (with that kwargs) and point both of them to same view.

Comment: Thats exactly my question. How to implement both list and detail view in 1 APIView is there is only 1 get method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `APIView`

For demo purpose I still use a queryset inside of the `retrieve/list` methods, but this is not mandatory you should put your own logic there.

```
class TestAPIView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'pk' in kwargs:
            return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = Test.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = TestSerializer(instance=instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        serializer = TestSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then in `urls.py` add this lines:

```
url(r'^test/$', TestAPIView.as_view(), name='test-list'),
url(r'^test/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', TestAPIView.as_view(), name='test-detail'),
```

or in newer django versions you can use the `path`

```
path('test/', TestAPIView.as_view(), name='test-list'),
path('test/<int:pk>/', TestAPIView.as_view(), name='test-detail),
```

### Using `ViewSet`

You'll need to add the mapping of the request method to your function in your urls definition.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class TestViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = Test.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = TestSerializer(instance=instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        serializer = TestSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then in `urls.py` add this lines:

```
url(r'^test/$', TestViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='test-list'),
url(r'^test/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', TestViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='test-detail'),
```

or in newer django versions you can use the `path`

```
path('test/', TestViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='test-list'),
path('test/<int:pk>/', TestViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='test-detail),
```

Comment: I have asked another question. May I be so rude to ask you this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64173280/django-rest-framework-share-class-instance-between-files