# Django REST Framework share class instance between files

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, authlib

I have some code in my apps.py's `ready()` method that loads some Oauth providers using the authlib module. Basically I am doing this (apps.py):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from authlib.integrations.django_client import OAuth
from django.core.cache import caches

class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'

    def ready(self):
        import api.receivers
        defaultcache = caches['default']
        from .modules.oauth import fetch_token
        from .models import OauthProvider, OAuth2Token

        oauth = OAuth(fetch_token=fetch_token)
        print('settings oauthproviders')
        allproviders = OauthProvider.objects.all()
        for provider in allproviders:
            oauth.register(
                name=provider.name,
                client_id=provider.client_id,
                client_secret=provider.client_secret_decrypted,
                access_token_url=provider.access_token_url,
                access_token_params=provider.access_token_params,
                authorize_url=provider.authorize_url,
                authorize_params=provider.authorize_params,
                api_base_url=provider.api_base_url,
                client_kwargs=eval(provider.client_kwargs),
            )

        print(OAuth2Token.objects.get(name='enelogic'))
        defaultcache.set('oauth', oauth)
        #defaultcache.get('oauth') # <--- this line gives error
```

Error:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Thread 0x00001d4c (most recent call first):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 306 in wait
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 558 in wait
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 230 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 823 in __call__

Thread 0x00002b80 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 306 in wait
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 558 in wait
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 184 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 823 in __call__

Thread 0x0000609c (most recent call first):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 306 in wait
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 558 in wait
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_timeout.py", line 43 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00000ad4 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 209 in _read_line
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 227 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00005cf8 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_net_command.py", line 111 in send
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 370 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00005924 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 476 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 493 in __init__
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 103 in print_exception
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 163 in print_exc
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_log.py", line 130 in _pydevd_log_exception
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_log.py", line 160 in exception
  File "c:\Users\ericj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py", line 462 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 101 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\ericj\.virtualenvs\django_appelent_api-8qkCZVAS\lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\base_oauth.py", line 105 in __getattr__
```

This registers some oauth credentials (info) that can be used using the `oauth` variable (for example `oauth.get_authorization_url()` which gets me the authorize URL for that Oauth Provider.

Now, I have a lot of different files (I split my views.py into multiple files). How can I access this oauth variable in those files? I have tried with django caches, but then I get a weird overflow error when I try to access the variable.

How would you recommend?

The oauth class is working fine locally in the file, I just need to transfer it to some other file

Comment: Please add the error and sample of usage in a view

Comment: The sample of usage is there (that is the code giving the error). I will add the function call to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not extracting this in a separate python file (but still inside of your django app).

```
# oauth_providers.py

from authlib.integrations.django_client import OAuth

from .modules.oauth import fetch_token
from .models import OauthProvider, OAuth2Token


def register_providers(oauth):
    print('settings oauthproviders')
    allproviders = OauthProvider.objects.all()
    for provider in allproviders:
        oauth.register(
            name=provider.name,
            client_id=provider.client_id,
            client_secret=provider.client_secret_decrypted,
            access_token_url=provider.access_token_url,
            access_token_params=provider.access_token_params,
            authorize_url=provider.authorize_url,
            authorize_params=provider.authorize_params,
            api_base_url=provider.api_base_url,
            client_kwargs=eval(provider.client_kwargs),
        )

    print(OAuth2Token.objects.get(name='enelogic'))

oauth = OAuth(fetch_token=fetch_token)
```

```
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'

    def ready(self):
        from .oauth_providers import oauth, register_providers
        register_providers(oauth)
```

And now you can use it in your views by simple import

```
# views.py

from .oauth_providers import oauth

# do whatever with oauth
```

Yes, there are some caveats it will be a global variable (so don't try to change, I don't think you'll need to) and don't try to import the file in your `models.py` since this should be imported after the app is `ready()`.

Comment: I need it in my models and in my views (to get data). This is impossible?

Comment: How are you using this in the models? You might get away if you are using in a method, by doing the import in the method itself, not on top of `models.py`. It's a bad practice, but this will work.

Comment: Ok you are right not in models. Views is most important. Can you try to explain why it wouldnt work in a model and does in a view?

Comment: You are my absolute hero today. I am new to django and python (come from JS) and I am having trouble getting used to it. I got it to work. You did a great job!!!!

Comment: You can check django docs on this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded . Basically when the app is loaded the models are imported, that's why the `ready` method exists, it indicates you can use the app from now.

Comment: And this one :)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116362/django-rest-framework-serializer-usage-for-incoming-and-outgoing-data